# SimpleXML deserializer

Tags: java, simple-framework

I'm new to simple XML, and I run into a problem and not sure what I'm doing wrong,

I have the following XML:

```
    <BOOK>
    <CHAPTER>
      <TEXTLINE />
      <TEXTLINE > line of text.... </TEXTLINE>
      <TEXTLINE > line of text... </TEXTLINE>
    </CHAPTER >
    < CHAPTER >
      <TEXTLINE />
      <TEXTLINE > line of text.... </TEXTLINE>
    </CHAPTER >
<BOOK>
```

My java clases:

```
   @Root
    public static class Book {

        @ElementList(entry = "CHAPTER", inline = true) public ArrayList<ReceiptElement> chapter;

         public ReceiptElement getChapterLines() {
            if (this. chapter != null && this. chapter.size() > 0)
                return  chapter.get(0);
            else
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Root
    public static class Chapter {

        @ElementList(entry = "TEXTLINE", inline = true) public ArrayList<TextLine> lines;

       public ArrayList<TextLine> getLines() {
            return this.lines;
        }


     }

    public static class TextLine {

        private String textline;

        public  TextLine(@ElementMap(entry = "TEXTLINE") String text) {
            this.textline = text;
        }

        public String getTextline() { return  this.textline; }
    }
```

The Exception that I get:

> org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter '' does
>   not have a match in class TextLine

I have tried several variants without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First before parsing check whether your XML is valid. Here you can check in online XML validator : http://www.xmlvalidation.com/
Try removing the space between the `<CHAPTER>` tag and end the `<BOOK>`

I think this exception  `org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter '' does not have a match in class TextLine` is because you have not added @Root to TextLine class.

```
 <BOOK>
   <CHAPTER>
     <TEXTLINE/>
     <TEXTLINE> line of text.... </TEXTLINE>
     <TEXTLINE> line of text... </TEXTLINE>
   </CHAPTER>
   <CHAPTER>
     <TEXTLINE/>
     <TEXTLINE> line of text.... </TEXTLINE>
   </CHAPTER>
 </BOOK>
```

**Book.java**

```
@Root
    public class Book {
        @ElementList(entry = "CHAPTER", inline = true) public ArrayList<Chapter> chapter;

         public Chapter getChapterLines() {
            if (this. chapter != null && this. chapter.size() > 0)
                return  chapter.get(0);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

**Chapter.java**

```
@Root
public class Chapter {

    @ElementList(entry = "TEXTLINE", inline = true) public ArrayList<TextLine> lines;

   public ArrayList<TextLine> getLines() {
        return this.lines;
    }
 }
```

**TextLine.java**

```
 @Root
    public class TextLine {

        private String textline;

        public  TextLine(@ElementMap(entry = "TEXTLINE") String text) {
            this.textline = text;
        }
        public String getTextline() { return  this.textline; }
    }
```

Comment: XML is valid, and I remove the spaces, but that didn't make any change at all.

Comment: Your code had lots of error, changes are made and posted, try this once. Hope it will work now.

Comment: Shaggy, thanks. but  no, I try to with the @ROOT and didn't work either, still have the problem, I did a quick parse with string class for now, but I still want to see why is not working with simplexml

Comment: I hope you have used all the classes that are updated by me. Because not only `@Root` there are many other edits in my code.